# Can we pass priority and enabled from xls sheet for TestNg test?

Tags: selenium, testng

We have created selenium test cases and using TestNg framework to execute.

I have included priority and enabled along with @Test.

But the team expects they wanted to have priority and enabled from xls sheet for ease of use.

I have not seen any such blog that TestNg supports this.

Can anybody confirm that is it possible to implement??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Its very much possible to control the priority from an excel spreadsheet and based on that, assign corresponding priorities. For doing it you need an `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` implementation which you would wire in via a TestNG suite xml file.

Here's how you can do this.

I am using : TestNG 6.14.3 and for reading csv (for the sake of this example), I am using the library

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's how the sample csv looks like

```
| class_name                                                     | method_name | priority | 
|----------------------------------------------------------------|-------------|----------| 
| com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn50998867.TestclassSample | first       | 1        | 
| com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn50998867.TestclassSample | second      | 2        | 
| com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn50998867.TestclassSample | third       | 3        |
```

Sample test class on which the priority is to be applied

```java
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn50998867;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestclassSample {

  @Test
  public void second() {
    System.err.println("second");
  }

  @Test
  public void first() {
    System.err.println("first");
  }

  @Test
  public void third() {
    System.err.println("third");
  }
}
```

Here's how the TestNG listener (`org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` implementation) looks like:

```java
package com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn50998867;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;

public class PriorityTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
  private boolean initialised = false;
  private List<PriorityInformation> info = new ArrayList<>();

  private void init() {
    String file = System.getProperty("file.location", "src/test/resources/50998867.csv");
    try {
      CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
      List<String[]> allData = reader.readAll();
      boolean firstRow = true;
      for (String[] each : allData) {
        if (firstRow) {
          firstRow = false;
          continue;
        }
        info.add(new PriorityInformation(each));
      }
      initialised = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void transform(
      ITestAnnotation annotation, Class clazz, Constructor constructor, Method method) {

    PriorityInformation dummy =
        new PriorityInformation(method.getDeclaringClass().getName(), method.getName());
    if (!initialised) {
      init();
    }
    PriorityInformation found =
        info.stream()
            .filter(priorityInformation -> priorityInformation.equals(dummy))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(PriorityInformation.EMPTY);
    if (found.equals(PriorityInformation.EMPTY)) {
      return;
    }
    if (info.contains(dummy)) {
      annotation.setPriority(found.getPriority());
    }
  }
}
```

The TestNG suite xml file looks like below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="StackOverflow_50998867_suite" verbose="2">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn50998867.PriorityTransformer"/>
  </listeners>
  <test name="StackOverflow_50998867_test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn50998867.TestclassSample"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Here's how the output looks like:

```
...
... TestNG 6.14.3 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...
first
second
third
PASSED: first
PASSED: second
PASSED: third

===============================================
    StackOverflow_50998867_test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

===============================================
StackOverflow_50998867_suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Looks ok to me. Accepted the answer.

Comment: I implemented this and works fine.. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it's not possible to have Priority in TestNG xml file.

There was one issue raised back in 2017. and the **owner** and **collaborator** had decided to do nothing about that i.e status is **won't fix.**

You can refer the issue at this page : [TestNG_Issue_1324](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1324)

Currently, **priority** is only available with `@Test` and `preserve-order` is only available in **xml**.
If priority is more important than preserver-order then it won't be possible to override order with xml.
if priority is less important than preserve-order then the default value must change to false otherwise it will break priority when xml is used (maybe more, but the tests should highlight it quickly).