# Parameterize the priority and enabled in TestNG?

Tags: selenium, testng

I am using page object model for selenium for my test framework.

I have 145 test cases each test has priority and enabled = true along with @Test.

suppose if the team does not want to run few test cases they have to open the java files and make it enabled false or the other way I have to add parameters for enabled and they have to update the xml file.

This makes some time mess up on the xml and as well looks little tedious work.

is there any way I can pass this enabled as parameters from xls or csv?? Or any other way that it makes simple UI rather than editing java files or xml.

Comment: are you running on a maven based project?

Comment: If there is a pattern for tests included in run and not-run, you might think of using groups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we pass priority and enabled from xls sheet for TestNg test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998867/can-we-pass-priority-and-enabled-from-xls-sheet-for-testng-test)